# CKEditor colorbutton disappears when using quicktable plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, ckeditor

After adding the quicktable plugin to CKEditor, now the colorbutton plugin doesn't show (or even load).

In the config.js file I have:

```
config.extraPlugins = 'button';
config.extraPlugins = 'panel';
config.extraPlugins = 'panelbutton';
config.extraPlugins = 'floatpanel';
config.extraPlugins = 'justify';
config.extraPlugins = 'colorbutton';
config.extraPlugins = 'quicktable';
```

If I reverse the order of the last two to be:

```
config.extraPlugins = 'quicktable';
config.extraPlugins = 'colorbutton';
```

Then the colorbutton plugin loads and works but the quicktable plugin no longer loads.

Versions:

- CKEditor 4.3.3
- Colorbutton 4.3.5
- Quicktable 4.5

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the answer to this is quite simple after I found examples of other extraPlugins configurations. A little embarrassing I have to admit since I was basically reassigning the value of extraPlugins instead of appending to it. The solution is:

```
config.extraPlugins = 'button,panel,panelbutton,floatpanel,justify,colorbutton,quicktable';
```

Everything shows up as expected.